# Сложный декоративный заголовок с двумя отдельными границами

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, адаптивная-верстка

Какое решение Вы можете предложить для создания такого заголовка?

[image]

Как видите, левая полоска не явлется `border-left`, т. к. её длина (вернее, высота) не равна истинной высоте блока.

Я сам пробовал "нарисовать" левую полоску вручную, т. е. в виде отедльного блока со стилями и позиционированием, но мне такое решение не очень нравится, потому как совершенно лишено адаптивности (в мобильных версиях заголовки могут не уместиться в одну строку). Что-нибудь ещё возможно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таких случаях традиционно пользуются псевдо-элементами `::before` и `::after`, потому что они позволяют экономить на мусоре в разметке.

Собственно, одну полоску рисуем бордером, другую — псевдо-элементом. По-моему, выбор произвольный. Я не заметил, чтобы это вызывало какие-то проблемы на узких экранах. (Или я неправильно понял ваше задание — у вас многострочный пример отсутствует.)

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-left: 3px #666 solid;
}
h1::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block; position: absolute;
  left: -3px; right: 0; bottom: -5px; height: 2px;
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</section>
<section style="width: 6em">
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, замечательное решение!